# How come localStorage isn't accesable as an object?

Tags: javascript

How come you need to use a method to access localStorage like:

```
localStorage.setItem('name', 'content');
```

An API that allowed something like

```
localStorage.name = 'content';
```

would be much easier to work with. Also how come it only allows strings?

Comment: If you are working with AngularJS, you might find [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) useful.

Comment: 1. You don't. (user3081756 already covered this). 2 - you'd have to look at the discussions around LocalStorage at the time it was proposed and details of it's final spec and implementation released. Just use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse and you'll get an object in and out again. Naturally, not all properties/attributes of an object are serializeable and there is potential for information loss in the process. A perfect example is an HTML element with attached event handlers.

Comment: To clearify, I didn't ask because I needed to solve the problem. But rather wondered about the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An API that allowed something like
>
> ```
> localStorage.name = 'content';
> ```
>
> would be much easier to work with.

**It does**. You can use that instead of `setItem` if you prefer. From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-storage-interface):

> The supported property names on a `Storage` object are the keys of each key/value pair currently present in the list associated with the object.

The downside to doing that is that it cannot be shimmed on browsers that don't support web storage natively, whereas the `setItem`/`getItem` API can be.

> Also how come it only allows strings?

Because that's the simplest thing to do. Simple APIs are easier and faster to implement and easier to test (remember the goal was to get multiple vendors to support this quickly — and it worked). If you need something richer, you can use JSON or XML or whatever other form you like, serialized to and from strings. Just like HTTP.

Comment: this is the best day of my life.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily, you can assign localstorage value as such, `localstorage.name="somename"` will give you the name object which you can access using `localstorage.getItem` or `localstorage["name"]` or `localstorage.name` in any such way we get an object's properties. Found in the [MSDN links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg142799(v=vs.85).aspx#_session).